# Attempting to store an object, but cannot pickle ttk class

Tags: python, tkinter, pickle

I am attempting to store a filepath to a file so that when my application is opened, the filepath can be loaded back in and not have to be re-entered. To do this, I am trying to use the pickle module to "dump" the data to a file. However, I get the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "H:\Documents\Python Scripts\GUI.py", line 71, in <lambda>
    ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Browse", command=lambda:askfile(usbpath)).grid(column=2,row=2,sticky = E)
  File "H:\Documents\Python Scripts\GUI.py", line 26, in askfile
    pickle.dump(pathtype, f)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'tkapp'>: attribute lookup tkapp on __main__ failed
```

I do not understand how to avoid this. My full code is the following:

```
#Modules
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import pickle
import shutil

#Functions
def popup(info):
    popup = Tk()
    popup.wm_title("Attention")
    popup.attributes("-toolwindow",1)
    label = ttk.Label(popup, text=info)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    ttk.Button(popup, text="OK", command=popup.destroy).pack()
    popup.mainloop()

def stopProg(e):
    root.destroy()
def statuslabel(window, message):
    ttk.Label(window, text=message).grid(column=2, row=1)
def askfile(pathtype):
    filename = askopenfilename(parent=mainframe,title='Choose a file')
    pathtype.set(filename)
    f = open('store.pickle','wb')
    pickle.dump(pathtype, f)
    f.close()

def copyfiles(src,dst):
    sourcefile = src.get()
    if sourcefile.endswith(".txt"):
        try:
            shutil.copy(dst.get(),r'H:\Documents\folder\backups')
            shutil.copy(sourcefile,dst.get())
            statuslabel(mainframe, "Done")
        except IOError:
            statuslabel(mainframe, "Error")
            popup("Error occured: Please check your paths")
    else:
        popup("Bad filetype or no file selected")
#GUI 
root = Tk()
root.title('PPSSPP Save Management')
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding = "3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

try:
    open('store.pickle','x').close()
except FileExistsError:
    statuslabel(mainframe, "Load")

f = open('store.pickle', 'rb')
try:
    usbpath = StringVar()
    usbpath.set(pickle.load(f))
except EOFError:
    usbpath = StringVar()
try:
    homepath = StringVar()
    homepath.set(pickle.load(f))
except EOFError:
    homepath = StringVar()
f.close()

usbpath_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe,width = 60,textvariable=usbpath)
usbpath_entry.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W,E))
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="USB(PSP) Path").grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=W)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Browse", command=lambda:askfile(usbpath)).grid(column=2,row=2,sticky = E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="PC (PPSSPP) Path").grid(column=1,row=3,sticky=W)
homepath_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe,width = 60,textvariable=homepath)
homepath_entry.grid(column=1,row=4, sticky=(W,E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Browse", command=lambda:askfile(homepath)).grid(column=2, row =4,sticky=E)

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="USB -> PC", command=lambda:copyfiles(usbpath,homepath)).grid(column=2,row=5,sticky=(N,S,W,E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="PC -> USB", command=lambda:copyfiles(homepath,usbpath)).grid(column=2,row=6,sticky=(N,S,W,E))
```

Comment: You are attempting to pickle a widget rather than the text in the widget. Is that really what you're wanting to do? Why are you using pickle rather than just writing the path to a file?

Comment: I don't need to store the widget, I should only need to store the text (file path) within the widget.

Answer (score 1):

This button calls askfile and sends it a StringVar()

```
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Browse", command=lambda:askfile(usbpath)).grid(column=2,row=2,sticky = E)
```

the function then tries to pickle the StringVar, not the filename

```
def askfile(pathtype):  ## pathtype=StrinVar
    ## omitted code
    pickle.dump(pathtype, f)
```

Comment: I do not know what the OP intended to do, so can only explain why the error message was presented.  Assuming is generally incorrect and leads to wasted time, as a general rule over all threads.

Comment: @CurlyJoe: the very first words of the question are "I am attempting to store a filepath to a file". I asked for (and got) clarification that they do indeed only need the text from the widget and not the actual widget.

Comment: It was an answer at least, and not just a restatement of the error message with a question as to why pickle is being used and instead of writing to a file, which does not help the OP in any way.  Note that the clarification that you take credit for was after I posted.

Comment: I'm still unsure of what to do. Is there a simple way to only pickle the file path text, or is there a different method is should be using?

Comment: I have figured out that by using .get(), I can store the filepath and not the widget. But now I am running into an additional problem, which is that the pickle dump seems to overwrite the last value instead of appending it. (Should I make a new question for this?)